# Insert another popuproot like visual root in a UWP app

Tags: popup, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app that uses a few ContentDialogs.
I see that they appear in the PopupRoot visual tree. I need another PopupRoot-like visual tree on top of all other visual trees that will have a semi-transparent background with a busy indicator that will prevent the user from interacting with the app while preserving the app look and state of the app until the busy indicator is done.

As shown in the image below visual studio does this when debugging to inject the live visual tree tools. (It is the Grid below the PopupRoot).

[image: Visual studio does this when debugging to inject the live visual tree tools.]

Since the source code of UWP/WinRT is not available I am having a hard time figuring this out. I found the WPF source for the PopupRoot but it is only marginal helpful.

If this is not possible I will have to implement my own popup root in the main RootScrollViewer visual tree and display all my dialogs there. Which will be a decent amount of work I would like to avoid.

Comment: Are you saying you want to show a Please wait/Application Busy type view without giving end user an option to click anything on screen?

Comment: Essentially yes, What is in this layer is irreverent. I would just like to make sure it appears in front of the PopupRoot.

Comment: Did you get a chance to explore Template 10? There is something called BusyPage. You should definitely see into that. [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) Create a new project as Minimal page and check Busy Page.

Comment: I looked at the example you suggested. And yes that is what I will have to do if I cannot accomplish my goal. Thanks for the reference it will be helpful.

Comment: Keep in mind that XAML natively supports overlapping of the controls. For example, imagine a <Grid><Button /><Button /></Grid>. These two buttons appears one on the top of the other. So you don't need a second PopupRoot, simply play with visibility of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "shell" page that contains a Frame which will contain your app's pages and after it you can define some kind of busy indicator, which you will then trigger on/off when you need it. Because it is defined after the frame in the XAML tree, it will appear on top of it.

Here is a snippet of what would be inside the `AppShell.xaml` page

```
<Grid>
   <Frame x:Name="AppFrame" />
   <Grid Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="BusyIndicator">
      <ProgressRing />
      ... etc.
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In the code-behind `AppShell.xaml.cs` you could provide a public method:

```
public void SetBusy( bool visible )
{
    BusyIndicator.Visibility = 
       visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

And now anytime you need to turn the busy indicator on, you would do something like this:

```
( Window.Current.Content as AppShell ).SetBusy( true );
```

This is definitely not the cleanest solution, you should encapsulate this in some way so that you do not need to query the current window, but the basic idea holds.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the answer is no. I ended up implementing my own popup root in the main RootScrollViewer visual tree like I stated in my question abandoning the ContentDialog Control.

Thanks everyone who replied trying to help!